# When creating expression in SSRS 2016 Round() function third param errors out

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

What am I doing wrong when using the Round() function?  In the end I'm trying to return a number to show a dollar figure (not the data type just the format of $####.## as an example).

When I use the Round() function the following way it works fine and rounds up...

```
=Round(125.239, 2)
```

**Output would be 125.24**

The Round() function I'm using in the Expression is the following...

```
=Round(125.239, 2, 1)
```

For some reason that throws an error.

> Argument matching parameter 'mode' narrows from 'Integer' to
>   'System.MidpointRounding'

What am I doing wrong?  To add to my question, I should say that I'm trying to use "1" as the third param to **ROUND DOWN** the output getting "125.23" as the end result.

Comment: This worked for my configuration. What the version of your database ? please.

Comment: @pascalsanchez the error is a VB.Net error, not SQL Server. The OP isn't doing this in SQL, they're doing it in an SSRS expression. The version of the database has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSRS uses the VB.Net functions, so instead try:

```
=Round(125.239, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Reference: [MidpointRounding Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Edit:

Based on the OP's comment, what that are actually after is the value correct to 2 decimal places, not rounded. This can be achieved by doing the following:

```
=Floor(125.239*100) / 100
```

Comment: I'm confused...  Both `ToEven` and `AwayFromZero` end up with the results "125.24".  Is it not possible to get "125.23" as the results?

Comment: Not with `ROUND`, no Arvo. I'll update my answer to show you how to get the result you're after.

Comment: Updated the answer for you, @ArvoBowen. What you're actually after here is `Floor`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and very helpful answer!!

Comment: I guess it was actually two questions in one.  I needed to find out why the Round function (third param) was not working for me which you covered as well as the fact I was looking for a different function altogether.  Nailed it!

Answer (score -1):

Can we see more of your code, Does it work if you just put in:

```
SELECT ROUND(125.239, 2, 1)
```

Rounding down is more of a truncate. The ROUND feature should work for you, but if you just use:

```
ROUND(125.239, 2, 1)
```

It will return 125.230. If you want it formatted correctly, I would do it like this:

```
CAST(ROUND(125.239, 2, 1) AS DECIMAL(18,2))
```

This returns 125.23. This will truncate the number to 2 decimal places with a following zero, then format it in the way you want.